# Meteor dynamic schema using aldeed Simple Schema package

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor app, I save schemas in a collection called ClassifiedsTemp, now I am trying load those schemas retrieved from DB to generate a form for them using auto form and simple schema packages. So I am using the code shown below, but I am always getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: existingKey.indexOf is not a function
```

any thoughts what I might be doing wrong/missing here? Thanks

Client js code:

```
            this.classTempArrayToJSON = function(classTempArray) {
                var tempSchemaObj = {};
                for(var i=0; i<classTempArray.length; i++){
                    if(classTempArray[i].fieldtype=='String'){
                        tempSchemaObj[classTempArray[i].fieldname] = {  type: classTempArray[i].fieldtype,
                                                                       label: classTempArray[i].fieldlbl,
                                                                       min: Number(classTempArray[i].minval),
                                                                       max: Number(classTempArray[i].maxval),
                                                                       optional: !classTempArray[i].required };

                    }
                }
                return tempSchemaObj;
            };


    Template.SchemaGenTemp.events({
       'click #createSchema': function(e, t){

          var x = ClassifiedsTemp.find({}).fetch(); 
          var schema = JSON.stringify(classTempArrayToJSON(x[1].fieldsList));

          console.log(schema);

          SampleClassColSchema = new SimpleSchema(schema); //Crash here...

          console.log('Done');    
       }
    });
```

Output from JSON.stringify example:

```
{"Test":{"type":"String","label":"Car Price","min":1,"max":1000000,"optional":true}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two concerns:

1. As Aleksei pointed out, you should not stringify your fieldsList.
2. `String` is an actual type, it should not be between quotes.

Knowing this, try this code out:

```
        this.classTempArrayToJSON = function(classTempArray) {
            var tempSchemaObj = {};
            for(var i=0; i<classTempArray.length; i++){
                if(classTempArray[i].fieldtype=='String'){
                    tempSchemaObj[classTempArray[i].fieldname] = {  type: String, // since it will always be 'String'
                                                                   label: classTempArray[i].fieldlbl,
                                                                   min: Number(classTempArray[i].minval),
                                                                   max: Number(classTempArray[i].maxval),
                                                                   optional: !classTempArray[i].required };

                }
            }
            return tempSchemaObj;
        };


Template.SchemaGenTemp.events({
   'click #createSchema': function(e, t){

      var x = ClassifiedsTemp.find({}).fetch(); 
      var schema = classTempArrayToJSON(x[1].fieldsList);

      console.log(schema);

      SampleClassColSchema = new SimpleSchema(schema); // No crash here...

      console.log('Done');    
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to pass an object as parameter to SimpleSchema constructor.

In this case you don't need to use `JSON.stringify` on fetched object.
Also you can use underscore `_.each()` method instead of `for()` loops.

Comment: So you believe I should pass the array from DB as is without calling JSON.stringify ?

Comment: Yes, actually you should pass each schema object of the fetched array to your schema constructor.


`_.each(yourSchemaArray, function(item) {    
  Schema = new SimpleSchema(item);    
});    
`

SimpleSchema won't work with a string passed to its constructor as an argument, it accepts only objects.


`var schema = classTempArrayToJSON(x[1].fieldsList);`
I beleive that var schema isn't an array, considering `Оutput from JSON.stringify example`, it is an object converted to string with `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Aleksei, apologies for the delayed reply. I tried exactly what you have mentioned and I got an error Uncaught Error: Invalid definition for field type field. This is the field which was passed to it from the array exactly as you described in your example. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Also if I just pass the array as is to the schema, how i can define the schema field name? Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry :) I missed that { type: String } had quotes.
Also you can reactively pass dynamic schema to [aldeed:autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform).
Check  this issue for example [issues-576](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/576)